# Why can't I use std::iterator<>::reference with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I tried to do this

```
template <class V>
class myiterator: std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, V>{
    reference a;
};
```

Like in this example

```
class myiterator: std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int>{
    reference a;
};
```

But I got an error "‘reference’ does not name a type". How can I use std::iterator<>::reference  with templates ?

Comment: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `reference` is declared in the base class, and the base class is a dependent type (its type depends on `V`). There are special rules that apply to this situation: when the compiler sees the name `reference`, it does not search the dependent base class scope, and therefore, does not find the name. In order to force the compiler to search dependent base class scopes, you must qualify the name.

You might think that `iterator::reference` would do the trick. Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. `iterator` as a shorthand for `std::iterator<std::random_access_tag, V>` is itself declared inside the base class as its "injected class name". So `iterator` will not be found either unless it is qualified by something.

You can type it out the long way: `typename std::iterator<std::random_access_tag, V>::reference a;`. A more readable way is:

```
using base = typename myiterator::iterator;
typename base::reference a;
```

You can use `base::` to force lookup in the base class scope during the rest of the `myiterator` class definition.

In C++20, `typename` can be omitted from these contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The name `reference` won't be found because nondependent name won't be looked up in dependent base class `std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, V>`, which depends on template parameter `V`.

You can make `reference` a dependent name as:

```
template <class V>
class myiterator: std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, V>{
    typename std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, V>::reference a;
};
```

On the other hand the non-template version doesn't have such issue.